# extract src from javascript function using bs4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

how can i extract the src from the code below using bs4 ?

the script show when i use request but i can't get the src from it

i tried page.get("src")

but it didn't work

```
<script>
    function hls() {
        document.getElementById("videowrapper_hls").innerHTML = '<iframe src="/redirect/dHlFVXhUNU1wTHB5T2ZnblorQ1k4aVVyV1JKRjRkUEpnaExzeVpUUHZDWmJkMGF2N0pPa3RPdDRQYjFHYmhRWnljclVXa0l0V0hLK3VuSElFTUExNVE9PQ==" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="700" height="430" allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true"></iframe>'

        if ($('#videowrapper_video').length > 0) {
          document.getElementById("videowrapper_video").innerHTML = ''
        }

        if ($('#videowrapper_fembed').length > 0) {
          document.getElementById("videowrapper_fembed").innerHTML = ''
        }

        if ($('#videowrapper_gounlimited').length > 0) {
          document.getElementById("videowrapper_gounlimited").innerHTML = ''
        }

        if ($('#videowrapper_mixdrop').length > 0) {
          document.getElementById("videowrapper_mixdrop").innerHTML = ''
        }

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend Using Regular Expression as follows :

```
html = '''<script>
    function hls() {
        document.getElementById("videowrapper_hls").innerHTML = '<iframe src="/redirect/dHlFVXhUNU1wTHB5T2ZnblorQ1k4aVVyV1JKRjRkUEpnaExzeVpUUHZDWmJkMGF2N0pPa3RPdDRQYjFHYmhRWnljclVXa0l0V0hLK3VuSElFTUExNVE9PQ==" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="700" height="430" allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true"></iframe>'

        if ($('#videowrapper_video').length > 0) {
          document.getElementById("videowrapper_video").innerHTML = ''
        }

        if ($('#videowrapper_fembed').length > 0) {
          document.getElementById("videowrapper_fembed").innerHTML = ''
        }

        if ($('#videowrapper_gounlimited').length > 0) {
          document.getElementById("videowrapper_gounlimited").innerHTML = ''
        }

        if ($('#videowrapper_mixdrop').length > 0) {
          document.getElementById("videowrapper_mixdrop").innerHTML = ''
        }

    }
</script>'''

import re
match = re.search(r'<iframe src=\"(.*?)\"', html)
src = match.group(1) if match is not None else ''   
print(src)
```

Outputs:

```
/redirect/dHlFVXhUNU1wTHB5T2ZnblorQ1k4aVVyV1JKRjRkUEpnaExzeVpUUHZDWmJkMGF2N0pPa3RPdDRQYjFHYmhRWnljclVXa0l0V0hLK3VuSElFTUExNVE9PQ==
```